# 45 and wanting to start Ed.D am I too old?!

Tags: career-path

I am in my 23rd year of teaching at the public schools.  I love what I do and as some refer... I am a 'lifer.'  I am 45 yrs. old and wanting to start my Ed.D. The program is estimated to be completed in 3yrs as I already have an MA and 18 additional graduate course work hours that some will likely transfer.  I believe I will be 48 or 49 when I finish.  My goal is to take the Ed.D.  and my 26/27 yrs public education and move into a university setting and apply and pour into aspiring students who wish to become teachers as well as be a supervisor of student teachers.  I have thought of other ideas too like working more at a district level within a school district where my Ed.D. in Educational Leadership with the emphasis in curriculum and instruction or special education could be of value.  My greatest concern is I will do all this work for nothing and be considered too old and overlooked.  Anyone have any wisdom to impart as I ponder this decision????

Comment: Well, I started my Ph.D. at 56.  And finished it!

Comment: Anecdotal: In my program, the average age of those pursuing an EdD is likely below 45, but not horribly so.

Comment: Judging by the quality of the administrators in my children's district, good administrators are in short supply.